# AsyncTask doubts regarding the activities flow

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I got some concerns about AsyncTask that I could not clarify when reading the documentation.

My app main Activity runs several AsyncTask's when it's created. These AsyncTask's mostly download data or retrieve data from the DB.

1. If I go to a different Activity, will the AsyncTask's created on
   this one continue executing? Or will they stop working and leave the
   task half done? If so, will they go on somehow when getting back to
   this activity?
2. In order to start one of the activities from the
       one that is running the AsyncTask's, I need one of the AsyncTask's
       to be fully executed. How do I set this constraint? Could you show
       me some sample code of this, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I go to a different Activity, will the AsyncTask's created on this one continue executing? Or will they stop working and leave the task half done? If so, will they go on somehow when getting back to this activity?

Yes, it will continue to run.  This can be a bit of a double-edged sword as it will typically also hold on to the Activity instance, causing it to live beyond its `onDestroy()` callback, which is not ideal.  If the task you are running does not have the same lifecycle needs as the Activity itself, it may be better placed into a Service.

> In order to start one of the activities from the one that is running the AsyncTask's, I need one of the AsyncTask's to be fully executed. How do I set this constraint? Could you show me some sample code of this, please?

There are way too many ways to do this, many depending on the architecture of your application, to provide specific sample code...but here are a few higher level ideas.  Since AsyncTask provides a simple callback method on the main thread (`onPostExecute`) when the task execution is complete, you can set a flag at that point.  Or perhaps simply check for the existence of whatever data the AsyncTask is retrieving from any code where the Activity would be launched.  Again, a Service would provide good context for this, as multiple Activities could connect to the service and check the task status before moving forward.

Another option, depending on your application, is to have the result of the task dumped into a ContentProvider.  ContentProviders include a nice interface for notifying observers of changes without resorting to global Broadcast Intents.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Ive done something similar to this before using Intents and Broadcast Receivers.

If you get the Async tasks to send a global or app-wide intent when they are finished, its easy enough to have a receiver pick it up if you construct them properly. By having a receiver created when you push a new activity onto the stack, and have the receiver close when an activity is paused, there will always be a receiver out there to grab the intent and be told that the (example: data is downloaded from the db) and act on that.

If you try and start an activity that requires that data, you can either deny the creation of that activity if the intent hasn't been found yet, or create the activity and have it put up a progress bar or something while the data finishes downloading, then have its receiver act on the intent when it arrives.

Hope this helps.